# Kibana 6.5 pointing to multiple elasticsesrch nodes

Tags: linux, elasticsearch, kibana

I was wondering if kibana 6.5.0 supports the option to pointing to multiple elasticsearch nodes.

I have 5 elasticsearch nodes in a cluster setup and i want point a single kibana instance to those nodes (i do not want to use querying node or similar).

I tried using the tag in yaml file "elasticsearch.host" but only supports 1 elasticsearch URL.

Also i tried with the tag "elasticsearch.url" and "elasticsearch.urls" as specified in a specifyc section in elastic.io but it does not work... Basically it crashes.

Any idea if with this specyfic version of Kibana i can point to multiple cluster nodes? If so any example how you would use the tag?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible, this version does not support multiple hosts.

This feature was implemented in version [6.6](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/6.6/release-notes-6.6.0.html#enhancement-6.6.0).

To be able to point kibana to multiple hosts you will need to upgrade your stack.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there an eassy way to upgrade from kibana 6.5 to 6.6 without uninstall the packet in linux Ubuntu? I can just upgrade kibana 6.5 and still working with elasticsearch nodes in version 6.5?

Comment: You can follow the [rolling upgrade](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.5/rolling-upgrades.html) documentation, but keep in mind that both 6.5 and 6.6 already reached EOL and are not supported anymore. If you want to proceed, make sure that you are updating to the correct version, update from 6.5 to 7.X could break a lot of things. And no, you need to upgrade both Elasticsearch and Kibana, they need to be on the same version.